# DraggableScrollableSheet with a header and list view

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am not able to create

```
return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.2,
        minChildSize: 0.2,
        maxChildSize: 1,
        snapSizes: const [.4, 1],
        snap: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
          return SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                  decoration: createSheedBoxDecoration(),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      createDragHandle(),
                      createListItemTitleWidget(),
                      Expanded(
                          child:
                              linesListViewWidget(busLines, scrollController)),
                    ],
                  )));
        });
```

createDragHandle and createListItemTitleWidget are just widgets but if try to expand the DraggableScrollableSheet by clicking on them nothing happens.

I have also tried to use `IgnorePointer` on them but since the scrollController is sent to the list view only by selecting and dragging list view item I can expand DraggableScrollableSheet.

For more clarity here are createDragHandle and createListItemTitleWidget

```
  Widget createDragHandle() {
    return IgnorePointer(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 8),
            height: 8,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
  Widget createListItemTitleWidget() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 16, bottom: 16),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const Icon(Icons.directions, size: 24),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 8.0,
          ),
          Text(
            "Header",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
 if (index == 0) {
            return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [createDragHandle(), createListItemTitleWidget()],
                ));
          }
```

Inside my list view and it works